# Google Analytics not loading in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics

When I try log in to Google Analytics in Chrome, the page doesn't load. Very odd. I just get what you see here:

[image]

I've never experienced it before recently, and it works on the same computer with Safari, but for about a week now it hasn't worked on Chrome. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you running?

Answer (score 39):

Likely an ad blocking plugin that had its ad database updated.

Comment: I tried it on incognito and different browsers but it's still not working. The site is down [only for me](http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/analytics.google.com.html).

Comment: I tried on Incognito mode and different browsers but it is still not working. I also tried this on Chrome: Settings > Reset > Restore settings to their original defaults. I am still experiencing the same issue reported in this question.

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is old but I thought I'd add my answer.

For me it was adblocker on chrome. Click the hand in the red octagon next to your address bar. Go to options and click "show adds on web or domain", add the the domain https://www.google.com/analytics/ and that should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

[Clear your cache](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95582) and [disable any plugins](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142064) that might be interfering.

Comment: This should be the first thing to try!! I have a similar situation, page loaded with all the charts, but no data in them. The "loading" label just stay there. I finally did a full reload (ctrl+shift+r) and it works again.

Answer (score 2):

Try in incognito or in private browsing as it will stop interference from extensions especially adblocking extensions

Answer (score 1):

I tried on Incognito mode and different browsers but it is still not working. I also tried this on Chrome: Settings > Reset > Restore settings to their original defaults. I am still experiencing the same issue reported in this question. When I gave up trying everything on Windows, I tried from an iPhone (not the app, but visiting Google Analytics from a web browser on my iPhone 7 Plus in Chrome, no success. Then I moved to OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.5, and still the same, Google Analytics was not working. After spending several minutes trying, maybe for about an hour or more without success, it suddenly started working everywhere.

My conclusion is that most likely this was a bug in Google Analytics. I should have tested my Internet speed to see if the cause was poor Internet speed, but other pages were loading correctly. So I assume it was simply some kind of bug in Google Analytics.

EDIT: Today I am experiencing the same problem, and this is about 24 hours after the answer above that I posted yesterday. I went to http://www.speedtest.net/ to test my Internet speed, and these are the results:

Ping: 6ms
Download: 2.68 Mbps
Upload: 5.17 Mbps

Then I saw a pop-up telling me that an internal error had happened, and please close and open again the browser. This was definitely a bug in Google Analytics' service.

This is what I was seeing today, with Google Analytics never loading:

[image]

Comment: Mac OS here: restarting Chrome worked for me, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that google analytics wasn't collecting data from some users using browsers like Chrome and Firefox, and also when the users were active on my website, google's Real Time Reporting didn't work.

I found out that the users were using browser plugins like: AdBlock or disconnect.me wich were blocking the data collection.

I hope this helps someone because google brought me here while I was searching the internet for a solution to my problem. 
And with some bits from here and some bits from there I managed to figure out what my problem was.
Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't the question of why a page doesn't load.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Chrome, OSX), but I found out it had something to do with my extensions, as Google Analytics would properly load in Incognito Mode. In my case the extension Windscribe - Free VPN and Ad Blocker were preventing Analytics to load. I fixed it by whitelisting the domain.